# how can I apply a transition effect to texts I get from the array with buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'm trying to make a slider that I got my content from the array in JavaScript. how to handle it. what I want is that when I click the left and right buttons, so I want it to have a transition effect when the content changes.like opacity, scale ?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ibrahimgedik/3at4mgpq/23/);
Here's a copy of my project,I can do it with css, but I want to know how content from the array with javascript can have a transition effect.

```
const title = document.querySelector('.title');
const caption = document.querySelector('.caption');
const image = document.querySelector('.image');

var array = [
  {title:'Title 1', caption:'Caption 1', image:'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484417894907-623942c8ee29?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=889&q=80' },
  
  {title:'Title 2', caption:'Caption 2', image:'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544256718-3bcf237f3974?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=751&q=80' },
  
  {title:'Title 3', caption:'Caption 3', image:'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517694712202-14dd9538aa97?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80' }
];

var index = 0;
var sliderCount = array.length;

showSlide(index);

document.querySelector('#left-btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    index--;
    showSlide(index);

});
document.querySelector('#right-btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    index++;
    showSlide(index);
});

function showSlide(i) {
    index = i;

    if (i < 0) {
        index = sliderCount - 1;
    }

    if (i >= sliderCount) {
        index = 0;
    }
    
    title.textContent = array[index].title;
    caption.textContent = array[index].caption;
    image.setAttribute('src', array[index].image);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define classes `transition appear` and `transition disappear` for the `img` elements. Use your `css` `animation` and `transition` knowledge to write good properties for `.appear` and `.disappear` classes. Also, instead of toggling the `src`, give each image link its own `img` then add the `js` method `image.classList.toggle("appear")` for desired appearance, then remove the `appear` class by typing `image.classList.remove("appear")` and add `image.classList.toggle("disappear")` for desired disappearance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I am making a mistake in the algorithm, I cannot develop a very good algorithm yet,Thank you for your response and your time for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may use also the [`mousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) and [`mouseup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event) event to modify some css rules :

example with opacity and a short transition  https://jsfiddle.net/jbe2mtcx/

```js
const title = document.querySelector('.title');
const caption = document.querySelector('.caption');
const image = document.querySelector('.image');

var array = [{
    title: 'Title 1',
    caption: 'Caption 1',
    image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484417894907-623942c8ee29?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=889&q=80'
  },

  {
    title: 'Title 2',
    caption: 'Caption 2',
    image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544256718-3bcf237f3974?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=751&q=80'
  },

  {
    title: 'Title 3',
    caption: 'Caption 3',
    image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517694712202-14dd9538aa97?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80'
  }
];

var index = 0;
var sliderCount = array.length;

showSlide(index);

let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.containerSO button i.fas');
for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {

  btns[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    let slideContent = document.querySelectorAll('.containerSO > *:not(button)');
    for (i = 0; i < slideContent.length; i++) {
      slideContent[i].style.opacity = '0'
    }
  });

  btns[i].addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    let slideContent = document.querySelectorAll('.containerSO > *');
    for (i = 0; i < slideContent.length; i++) {
      slideContent[i].style.opacity = '1'
    }
  })

  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    let id = this.parentNode.getAttribute('id');
        let click = (id == "left-btn") ?  index-- :    index++;
    showSlide(index);

  });
}


function showSlide(i) {
  index = i;

  if (i < 0) {
    index = sliderCount - 1;
  }

  if (i >= sliderCount) {
    index = 0;
  }

  title.textContent = array[index].title;
  caption.textContent = array[index].caption;
  image.setAttribute('src', array[index].image);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.containerSO {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #000;
  animation: Fade 2s forwards;
}

.containerSO >* {
  transition: 0.15s
}

.title {
  color: white;
}

.caption {
  color: white;
}

.image {
  height: 150px;
}

#left-btn {
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#right-btn {
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<div class="containerSO">
  <h1 class="title">Title 1</h1>
  <p class="caption">Caption 1</p>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484417894907-623942c8ee29?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=889&q=80" alt="" class="image">
  <button id="left-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
  </button>
  <button id="right-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it really works, thank you again for your time :)

Comment: @İbrahim if this is the answer you look for you can accept  it, or just upvote it if you find it usefull but waiting for a better answer. Voted answer (down or up) are usefull to sort out for others users with a similar question. ;)